# Is removing my upvotes and acceptance to an answer okay incase of confusion?

Tags: discussion

If I post a question and receives and answer. Then,  in general, I use to upvote if it make sense to me and accepts the answer if it is apt to the context of the question.

But I cannot say whether the answer is correct or wrong.

If once I get realize that the answer may be wrong. I think it is okay to remove my upvotes or acceptance in order to not endorse to new users that answer is correct.

Is it okay to do so? Or should I not upvote or accept till I am completely sure on the answer which may take a long amount of time.

Answer (score 4):

I think it's not just fine but you should remove the upvote and an unaccept the answer until you are sure that the answer is correct or not (note that this is just my personal suggestion, so it's not a policy). You could, for example, leave the upvote because you think the answer is useful, although it may not be (fully) correct. That's also fine (but if it turns out to be wrong, you should remove the upvote, so that it's not misleading). Of course, the answerer may not like the idea. However, once you know the answer was actually correct, you can upvote and accept it again. It may not be a good idea to share this with the answerer, as they may take it personally (that's why votes are anonymous), but you're free to explain your decision to the answerer, if you think they deserve an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is fully OK, and fully consistent with the site policies as well; there is a reason why such actions are indeed permitted by the site functionality.

IMO, the site policies should be even more relaxed in such matters: currently, you cannot remove your vote (up or down) after a certain time, unless the post gets edited - but I am not sure how useful such a restriction is (except maybe for forcing you to be more careful when voting, but I doubt this is useful either).

Answer (score 1):

I've grappled with this on rare occasions, where I can't undo unless the question or answer is edited. My metric for whether I'm going to edit, and probably piss someone off is:

- How much harm does it cause

If it's trivial, I might leave it, especially if it's just an upvote.  But I think, in the case of accepted answers, where it would cause harm, one just has to bite the bullet and edit the post and remove the acceptance.